# Constructing URL for Google Maps Location for iOS

Tags: ios, google-maps, ios5, uiwebview

I created a web view to open google maps.  I got no problems getting the location by CLLocationManager. However, I need to specify a query string like this: "hospital loc: [latitude], [longitude]" to put in the search box to locate the nearest hospitals. How can I implement this after I load "maps.google.com" in my web view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this :**

```
http://maps.google.com/?q=hospital+loc:+[latitude],+[longitude]
```

**Notes :**

1. Obviously replace with your desired latitude, longitude coordinates
2. Remember to properly encode the parameter passed to `q=`

Comment: When the webview started, maps.google.com asked again the current location. Nothing appears.

Comment: http://maps.google.com/?q=hospital+loc:37.785834,-122.406417 this perfectly work on a browser..